# ITK Filter slower in C++ than Python

Tags: python, c++, itk

I have made a module in Python using SimpleITK, which I tried to speed up by reimplementing in C++. It turns out to be quite a lot slower.

The bottleneck is the usage of the DisplacementFieldJacobianDeterminantFilter.

These two snippets give an example of the usage of the filters.

1000 generations: C++ = 55s, python = 8s

Should I expect the c++ to be faster?

```py
def test_DJD(label_path, ngen):

  im = sitk.ReadImage(label_path)

  for i in range(ngen):
    jacobian = sitk.DisplacementFieldJacobianDeterminant(im)


 if __name__ == '__main__':


    label = sys.argv[1]
    ngen = int(sys.argv[2])
    test_DJD(label, ngen)
```

And the c++ code

```cc
typedef itk::Vector<float, 3> VectorType;
typedef itk::Image<VectorType, 3> VectorImageType;
typedef itk::DisplacementFieldJacobianDeterminantFilter<VectorImageType >  JacFilterType;
typedef itk::Image<float, 3> FloatImageType;



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

std::string idealJacPath = argv[1];
std::string numGensString = argv[2];

int numGens;
istringstream ( numGensString ) >> numGens;



typedef itk::ImageFileReader<VectorImageType> VectorReaderType;
VectorReaderType::Pointer reader=VectorReaderType::New();
reader->SetFileName(idealJacPath);
reader->Update();
VectorImageType::Pointer vectorImage=reader->GetOutput();


JacFilterType::Pointer jacFilter = JacFilterType::New();

FloatImageType::Pointer generatedJac = FloatImageType::New();

for (int i =0; i < numGens; i++){
    jacFilter->SetInput(vectorImage);
    jacFilter->Update();
    jacFilter->Modified();
    generatedJac = jacFilter->GetOutput();
}
return 0;

}
```

I'm using the c++ ITK 4.8.2 and compiled in 'release' mode on Ubuntu 15.4. And the python SimpleITK v 9.0

Comment: Have you tried to profile it?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be benchmarking using loops. Using loops for benchmarking is not a good practice, because the compilers and interpreters does a lot of optimizations to them.

I believe that in here

```
for i in range(ngen):
    jacobian = sitk.DisplacementFieldJacobianDeterminant(im)
```

The python interpreter most probably realized that you are only using the last value assigned to the `jacobian` variable, therefore executing only ONE iteration of the loop. This is a very common loop optimization.

On the other hand, since you call a couple of dynamic method in the C++ version (`jacFilter->Update();`), is possible that the compiler could not infer that the other calls are not being used, making your C++ version slower since all the invocations to the DisplacementFieldJacobianDeterminant::update method are actually made.

Another possible cause is that the ITK pipeline in Python is not being forced to update, as you call explicitly the `jacFilter->Modified()` in C++ but this is not explicit in the Python version.